# Galeria imagenes pantalla completa

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Buenas a todos.

Quería mostrar una galeria de imágenes que ocupan toda la pantalla, y vi la opción de viewFlipper. El código funciona perfectamente, pero tarda mucho en cargar cuando las imágenes a mostrar pasan de 5.

¿Cómo puedo optimizar esto? He leído en stackOverflow inglés que es mejor usar un viewpager pero no encuentro ningún ejemplo que no implemente las tabs. Mi diea es muy sencilla, sólo quiero que aparezca la foto a pantalla completa y se cambie la imagen deslizando el dedo a derecha o izquierda y que cuando llegue a la última pase a la primera o de la primera pueda pasar a la ultima, como una cola circular.

¿qué me recomendáis? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, debes aportar más detalles e información de lo que has realizado, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys, perdon gracias por el link, lo tenré en cuenta pra próximas preguntas

Comment: gracias, @user2070274  esto para que tu pregunta pueda ser de ayuda a más desarrolladores, saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITADA**

Teniendo en cuenta que las imágenes las tienes almacenadas en local, en la carpeta Drawable, yo haría lo siguiente:

1. Creas un layout con una vista de tipo ViewPager.
2. Creas otro layout con una vista de tipo ImageView, para contener las imágenes del ViewPager.
3. Creas un xml de tipo array con las referencias a los drawables.
4. Creas una clase que extienda de PagerAdapter y le pasas el array creado en el punto anterior.
5. Seteas el viewPager con el adapter.

A continuación te muestro un ejemplo de todos los pasos.

1. nombre del archivo: activity_main.xml

   ```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent>

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/image_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
2. nombre del archivo: element_image.xml

   ```
   <FrameLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/item_image"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </FrameLayout>
   ```
3. nombre del archivo arrays.xml

   ```
   <array name="images">
       <item>@drawable/image_1</item>
       <item>@drawable/image_2</item>
       <item>@drawable/image_3</item>
       <item>@drawable/image_4</item>
   </array>
   ```
4. nombre del archivo: ImageAdapter.java

   ```
   public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

           private TypedArray images;
           private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

           public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
               images = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
               layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                       context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           }

       @Override
       public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

           View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.element_image, container, false);

           ImageView image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

           image.setImageDrawable(images.getDrawable(position));

           ((ViewGroup) image.getParent()).removeView(image);

           container.addView(image);

           return image;
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return images.length();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
           return view == object;
       }

       @Override
       public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
           container.removeView((ImageView) object);
       }
   }
   ```
5. nombre del archivo: MainActivity.java

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

       ViewPager imageGallery = findViewById(R.id.image_gallery);
       imageGallery.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
   }
   ```

   }

Creo que el código se ajusta ahora mejor a lo que querías
un saludo.

Comment: Muchíisimas gracias @D.Santamaria. No termino de ver como se pasan las fotos al imageAdapter desde la carpeta drawable. La clase Image Adapter es una clase dentro de la clase de la activty o una clase a parte en otro fichero?

Comment: De nada @user2070274, he editado la respuesta con una solución que se ajusta mejor a tus necesidades. Para conseguir que el scrolling sea circular implementa en MainActivity la interfaz ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.